Strictly use apex domain and additionally have Google index it
I'd like the general public to normally access my site via http://site.foo. But I'm OK with the occasional redirect of http://www.site.foo to http://site.foo
I have two issues currently with Google Cloud Storage and Search.

I have both site.foo and www.site.foo buckets setup. I can maintain two separate sets of HTML artifacts in each, updating both sets every time. But I'd rather just have one, site.foo.
How do I get Google indexing site.foo? It looked to me I could only do so against www.site.foo.

This is what I have set as DNS records in Namecheap



Type
Host
Value




Alias
@
site.foo.


CNAME
www
c.storage.googleapis.com.




Allow Google to index site.foo and not index www.site.foo. Look into the file robots.txt and also refer to this document: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/control-what-you-share

@JohnHanley The Google Search Console has Page is not indexed: URL is unknown to Google when I enter site.foo. But www.site.foo is fine. Will robots.txt fix that?

Did you read the documentation I linked? Did you research robots.txt?

Bote: Why are you concerned about which site Google indexes? It really does not matter which site Google indexes. Because of user convention, you should support both (site.foo and www.site.foo).

Check into the effects of HTTP permanent redirects on Google indexing. IIRC when Google receives a permanent redirect, it does not index the original page but does index the target link.

I think I've gotten this figured out. I'll post an answer once Google has (hopefully) crawled and caught up.
